# unity Newtonsoft JsonConvert make integer to float

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've try to convert .xls to .json using Unity and NewtonSoft.JsonConvert

But, it makes integer value to float

For example, there's List<Dictionary<string, object>> and one of pairs is <"ID", 1001>

When I Serialize this using JsonConvert.SerializeObject, the result is \"ID\": 1001.0,\r\n

I want make .xls to json and save this to file(.json) and keep integer variable's type.
(I mean, If value is 100, then result text file(.json) has "100" Not "100.0")

Please help.

```
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (table);
        JsonPath = "Assets/Plugins/ExcelToJson/Spreadsheet2.json";
        using (FileStream fileStream=new FileStream(JsonPath,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write)) {
            using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream, encoding)) {
                textWriter.Write (json);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (table);
```

with

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (table, tableFormatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
});
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer, but unfortunately my problem's not solved.
still intger's changed float.
New result : 

'{
  "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]], mscorlib]], mscorlib",
  "$values": [
    {
      "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
      "ID": 1002.0,
      "Name": "hero2",
      "NameKR": "기본영웅2",
      "EquipSkillList": "_",
      "SpineDataAsset": "_",
      "TestValue": 4.0
    },